Im developing a requirement where i have some content and table in a page and if table exceeds the page, then it must continue in next page in Java
I need a pdf file where it must contains borders on all side with some text content on top and table under the text, when the table exceeds the border, it must continue in the next page,
Im using PDFBox Library using Java, can anyone help me achieving this, Code follows
package PDF;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.Standard14Fonts;

public class PDF_Example {

    public static final String DEST = "21.pdf";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new PDF_Example().createPdf(DEST);
    }

    public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException {
        try (PDDocument document = new PDDocument()) {
            PDPage page = new PDPage();
            document.addPage(page);

            try (PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page)) {
                drawTable(contentStream, 80, 500, generateTableData());
                contentStream.setFont(new PDType1Font(Standard14Fonts.FontName.HELVETICA), 14);
                contentStream.setLineWidth(1f);
                
                
                float textX = 80;
                float textY = page.getMediaBox().getHeight() - 100; // Adjust as needed
                float startX = 50;
                float startY = 50;
                float width = page.getMediaBox().getWidth() - 100;
                float height = page.getMediaBox().getHeight() - 100;
                int linesNumber = 0;
                // Define the width of the paragraph
 // Adjust as needed
                
                // Define the line height
                float lineHeight = 14; // Adjust as needed
                
                // Define the text for the paragraph
                String text = 
                        
                        "This is a sample paragraph. It contains multiple lines of text to demonstrate how to create paragraphs in a PDF using Apache PDFBox in Java. Adjust the width and line height as needed to fit your requirements.";

                // Split the text into lines to fit the width
                String[] lines = fitTextToWidth(text, new PDType1Font(Standard14Fonts.FontName.HELVETICA), 12, width);

                // Write each line of text
                for (String line : lines) {
                    linesNumber = linesNumber + 1;
                    contentStream.beginText();
                    contentStream.newLineAtOffset(textX, textY);
                    contentStream.showText(line);
                    contentStream.endText();
                    textY -= lineHeight;
                    
                }
                System.out.print(linesNumber); 
                

                // Draw border lines


//                // Top border
                contentStream.setLineWidth(2);
                contentStream.moveTo(startX, startY);
                contentStream.lineTo(startX + width, startY);
                contentStream.stroke();

//                // Right border
                contentStream.setLineWidth(2);
                contentStream.moveTo(startX + width, startY);
                contentStream.lineTo(startX + width, startY + height);
                contentStream.stroke();

//                // Bottom border
                contentStream.setLineWidth(2);
                contentStream.moveTo(startX + width, startY + height);
                contentStream.lineTo(startX, startY + height);
                contentStream.stroke();
                
//                // Left border
                contentStream.setLineWidth(2);
                contentStream.moveTo(startX, startY + height);
                contentStream.lineTo(startX, startY);
                contentStream.stroke();
            }

            document.save(dest);
                   }
    }

    private List<List<String>> generateTableData() {
        List<List<String>> tableData = new ArrayList<>();
        tableData.add(List.of("Name", "Age"));
        tableData.add(List.of("John Doe", "30"));
        tableData.add(List.of("Jane Smith", "25"));
        tableData.add(List.of("Jane Smith", "25"));
        tableData.add(List.of("Jane Smith", "25"));
        tableData.add(List.of("Jane Smith", "25"));
        tableData.add(List.of("Jane Smith", "25"));
        tableData.add(List.of("Jane Smith", "25"));
        tableData.add(List.of("Jane Smith", "25"));
        tableData.add(List.of("Jane Smith", "25"));
        tableData.add(List.of("Jane Smith", "25"));
        tableData.add(List.of("Jane Smith", "25"));
        tableData.add(List.of("Jane Smith", "25"));
        tableData.add(List.of("Jane Smith", "25"));
        tableData.add(List.of("John Doe", "30"));
        tableData.add(List.of("Jane Smith", "25"));
        tableData.add(List.of("Jane Smith", "25"));
        tableData.add(List.of("Jane Smith", "25"));
        tableData.add(List.of("Jane Smith", "25"));
        tableData.add(List.of("Jane Smith", "25"));
        tableData.add(List.of("Jane Smith", "25"));
        tableData.add(List.of("Jane Smith", "25"));
        tableData.add(List.of("Jane Smith", "25"));
        tableData.add(List.of("Jane Smith", "25"));
        tableData.add(List.of("Jane Smith", "25"));
        tableData.add(List.of("Jane Smith", "25"));
        tableData.add(List.of("Jane Smith", "25"));
        tableData.add(List.of("Jane Smith", "25"));
        tableData.add(List.of("Jane Smith", "25"));
        tableData.add(List.of("John Doe", "30"));
        tableData.add(List.of("Jane Smith", "25"));
        tableData.add(List.of("Jane Smith", "25"));
        tableData.add(List.of("Jane Smith", "25"));
        tableData.add(List.of("Jane Smith", "25"));
        tableData.add(List.of("Jane Smith", "25"));
        tableData.add(List.of("Jane Smith", "25"));
        tableData.add(List.of("Jane Smith", "25"));
        tableData.add(List.of("Jane Smith", "25"));
        tableData.add(List.of("Jane Smith", "25"));
        tableData.add(List.of("Jane Smith", "25"));
        tableData.add(List.of("Jane Smith", "25"));
        tableData.add(List.of("Jane Smith", "25"));

        return tableData;
    }
    private String[] fitTextToWidth(String text, PDType1Font font, float fontSize, float width) throws IOException {
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] words = text.split("\\s+");
        StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
        float lineWidth = 150;

        for (String word : words) {
            float wordWidth = font.getStringWidth(word) / 1000 * fontSize;
            if (lineWidth + wordWidth > width) {
                lines.add(line.toString());
                line = new StringBuilder();
                lineWidth = 150;
            }
            line.append(word).append(" ");
            lineWidth += wordWidth;
        }

        lines.add(line.toString());
        return lines.toArray(new String[0]);
    }
    private void drawTable(PDPageContentStream contentStream, float x, float y, List<List<String>> tableData) throws IOException {
        final int rows = tableData.size();
        final int cols = tableData.get(0).size();
        final float rowHeight = 20f;
        final float tableWidth = 300f;
        final float tableHeight = rowHeight * rows;
        final float colWidth = tableWidth / (float) cols;
        final float cellMargin = 5f;

        // Draw table border lines
        float nextY = y;
        for (int i = 0; i <= rows; i++) {
            contentStream.moveTo(x, nextY);
            contentStream.lineTo(x + tableWidth, nextY);
            contentStream.stroke();
            nextY -= rowHeight;
        }
        float nextX = x;
        for (int i = 0; i <= cols; i++) {
            contentStream.moveTo(nextX, y);
            contentStream.lineTo(nextX, y - tableHeight);
            contentStream.stroke();
            nextX += colWidth;
        }

        // Fill table content
        float textX, textY;
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            nextY = y - rowHeight * (i);
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                nextX = x + colWidth * j;
                contentStream.setFont(new PDType1Font(Standard14Fonts.FontName.HELVETICA), 14);
                textX = nextX + cellMargin;
                textY = nextY - 15;
                contentStream.beginText();
                contentStream.newLineAtOffset(textX, textY);
                contentStream.showText(tableData.get(i).get(j));
                contentStream.endText();
            }
        }
    }
}


The code is executable if you just add libraries to eclipse IDE
Refer this image as ive told you the concept
ive tried Adding borders, text content and table into the pdf page, but couldnt generate another page and couldnt continue the table into the next page, please let me know the exact approach where i can achieve this.

Obviously you need to check whether your textY has become too low (e.g. lower than startY) after decreasing it. If it is, apply finishing touches on the current page (border lines etc.), close the current contentStream, create a new page, create a new content stream for that new page, re-initialize textY, and continue showing text.

@mkl can you please suggest me with a code snippet to close current contentStream, generating new page, im just confused with the logic a bit, till the above code ive written what i can, but im stuck at implementing logic.

"can you please suggest me with a code snippet to close current contentStream, generating new page" - Have a look at Pratim Singha's answer to his own question here. His use case is slightly different but his problem is the same as yours, so the solution is similar to what you will need.
